# How to search only within bookmarks from the Microsoft Edge URL bar?

Tags: search, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

**Question**

Is it possible to only search within the bookmarks from the URL bar?

**Example**

Firefox has this feature, where you can prepend a search with an asterisk and then the search is only applied to bookmarks.

Here is an example that shows only my bookmarks in the result list:

[image]

This is useful since you get a shorter list to go through and it is easier to select an entry with the <kbd>arrow down</kbd> key and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If I leave out the asterisk, the result list also shows Google's suggestions and older searches:

[image]

**My research so far**

1. I've googled and it seems that this feature is not available for
   Edge.
2. I've also googled whether Google Chrome has this features
   since Microsoft Edge is based on the same engine Google is using,
   but there too, I haven't found any results.
3. The [reply](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/using-edge-how-do-i-do-a-search-within-my/33368c93-2597-4fbd-a96b-548915010af5) from user e.gray suggests that this feature doesn't
   exist. But that answer is from 2016.

Answer (score 4):

##### Update 10.07.2023

With Microsoft Edge Version 114.0.1823.67 (and maybe even with an earlier version as Boss Man [says below](https://superuser.com/a/1773948)), one can type asterik followed by the search term. So, it works now the same as in Firefox. Typing asterisk <kbd>*</kbd> will switch to the Favourites search.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus the URL bar
2. <kbd>*</kbd> [keyword]
3. <kbd>Arrow down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image]

##### Original answer

I don't think that feature exists.

The next best solution I've found is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the `Favourites` fly-out dialog
2. Enter your search term
3. Select the result you want and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit outdated but currently (`121.0.2277.128 (Official build) (64-bit)`), by default, edge support same shortcuts as firefox

- *** OR @favorites** search in bookmarks
- **% OR @tabs** search in tabs
- **^ OR @history**  search in history

See [How to search bookmarks or history in Firefox directly from the navigation bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1795334/how-to-search-bookmarks-or-history-in-firefox-directly-from-the-navigation-bar)

Notice, however, that if you change the shortcut for `Favorites|Bookmarks|History` in `Settings > Privacy,Search, and services > Address bar and search > Manage search engines` (or just paste this in addrbar `edge://settings/searchEngines`), this behavior will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now available in Edge in Version 111.0.1661.41 (Official build) (64-bit). It works exactly as in Firefox.

Go to Settings -> Privacy, search and services -> Address bar and search -> Enable/Disable Advanced Filter.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the final screen? I've got version 111.0.1661.43 (Official build) (64-bit) and navigated to `Address bar and search` but don't see `Enable/Disable Advanced Filter`. I've also searched for it with "Search settings" and googled for screenshots but didn't find it.

Comment: I know what you mean. In my company Edge with same version it doesnt show up. But on a personal machine it does. Weird. But here is an image from personal https://imgur.com/a/k7cGBjq

Comment: This is called Controlled Feature Roll-outs. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/controlled-feature-roll-outs-in-microsoft-edge/m-p/763678

Answer (score 0):

The *KEYWORD works on Edge too for me, despite the fact that I do not see the setting to enable the filters. Hopefully this should resolve the issue for the poster.