# How to search bookmarks or history in Firefox directly from the navigation bar?

Tags: firefox, search

Is there a way to quickly search bookmarks or history for a page in Firefox's navigation bar? I understand Firefox's navigation bar by default searches bookmarks and history along with other things altogether, but I would like Firefox to search only bookmarks or history and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

- In *Settings*, in the *Search* box, type `bar sug`.
- Select *Change settings for other address bar suggestions*.
- Remove check-marks from all except *Bookmarks*.
- Also turn off other suggestions, e.g., from the web, from sponsors.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are default shortcuts:

[image]

The default for bookmarks is `*` and history is `^`. That means, type `*` or `^` followed by space to limit search scope.